# If a set can't contain identical elements, how can one element be less than or EQUAL to another element

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm studying set theory. I understand that a set can't contain identical elements. However when I read about partially ordered sets and the introduction of "$\leq$" I get confused by some sentences like:

"Given elements $a,b$ in a set $L$ we impose the axiom: 
If $a\leq b$ and $b\leq a$, then $a=b$."

How can $a=b$ if the set can't contain identical elements?

Comment: It's misleading to say that a set cannot contain identical elements. It's just that if an element is repeated, then the set is exactly the same.

Comment: Different variables can still represent the same element of a set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an analogy. No two people are the same. If Person A has the same mother as Person B and they are not twins and where born on the same day then Person A and Person B are the same Person.

Comment: "No two people people are the same" No, no two *distinct* people are the same. I am a person, and I am also a person. We are the same person. More generally, different variables need not refer to different elements; if $a,b\in P$ then it might be the case that $a = b$.

Comment: It is not a formal example so I think your comment raises more questions than it answers. Wouldn't the statement that no two distinct people are the same be redundant? If there were two seperate people who where identical in every way would they be considered distinct? Clearly trying to answer such questions would purely be a matter of definitions, of which there are none at hand for this example.

Comment: Yes, the statement that no two distinct people are the same is tautologous. It amounts to the statement $\forall x y,x\ne y\to x\ne y$. But it is important to recognize the difference between this (trivially true) statement and the false statement $\forall x y,x\ne y$. In English, we often insert an implicit distinctness condition on double quantifiers (i.e. "two people cannot be in the same place at the same time"), but mathematical english does not do this (when used carefully), and it is important to notice this.

Answer (score 0):

Although identical objects always have the same value, two objects that have the same value are not in general identical: the equality refers to their values matching.

Thus we could say that 'a' represents the average number of children of people whose names begin with 'A',
and 'b' represents the average number of children of people whose names begin with 'B'. And it might be that a=2.3 and b=2.3, so they are equal, but they do not refer to the same thing, and so they would be different elements of the set 'average number of children of various large groups of people'.
However we cannot have 2 distinct members of that set which are both "the average number of children of people whose names begin with 'A' ".

Comment: I wonder whether introducing an "object's value" is really needed to answer this question; it seems to cloud the issue, I think. I think Carl Mummert's comment hits the target. Welcome to Math Stack.

Comment: @311411 Carl Mummert's comment was that different variables can refer to the same element of a set. Although this is true, the question was specifically about the fact that two different elements of a set can be equal, not that a single element can be referred to by different variables. That is why having the same value is relevant. It makes them equal although they are not identical. If they were identical then they would not be distinct elements. Thank you for your welcome!